# How to delete a particular line using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

The following script takes pid(process id) interval in seconds and duration in minutes as input. I want to add only the data in output.txt and remove reamining data but this is not happening . Please help

```
    #!/bin/bash
pid=$1
interval=$2
duration=$3

#to get current time
now="$(date +"%r")"
echo $now
# to set duration in seconds
let "duration=$duration * 60"
end=$((SECONDS+duration))

if [ $( ls ~/output.txt ) ]
        then
                 rm -f ~/output.txt
fi


while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]
do

        echo "$(pidstat -h -p $pid -d -r -u -w)"
        output="$(pidstat -h -p $pid -d -r -u -w)"
        echo "$(pidstat -h -p $pid -d -r -u -w)" >> ~/output.txt
        sleep $interval
done
lines="$(wc -l < ~/output.txt)"
echo $lines
c=1
while [ $c -le $lines ]
do


        if (( $c % 4 != 0 ))
                then
                         sed -i "${c}d" ~/output.txt
        fi

        c=`expr $c + 1`
done
liness="$(wc -l < ~/output.txt)"
echo $liness
echo duration:$duration interval:$interval processId:$pid
```

Comment: Your question is **unclear**, you should provide an example of the *input* and the desired *output* as well as a *complete, minimal and verifiable example* of the code that you tried and does not work. Moreover, you should describe better what you are trying to accomplish, as it is not immediately clear. E.g, *"and remove reamining data but this is not happening"* ..what is reamining data? what is not happening? what have you tried?

Comment: `if [ $( ls ~/output.txt ) ];` is better written `if [ -f ~/output.txt ]` which is better written (IMO) `if test -f ~/output.txt`, but the entire check is unnecessary.  Just write `rm -f ~/output.txt`.  If the file does not exist, this becomes a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the lines of a file and invoking `sed -i` on each line is not a good approach.   If you want to delete every 4th line of ~/output.txt, just do:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk 'NR%4' ~/output.txt > $tmp; mv $tmp ~/output.txt
```